# removing redundant type in Interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I have following interfaces

```
public interface IRevision<TRevisionType>
{ ... }

public interface IRevisionLog
{ ... }

public interface IRevisionControl<in TRevision, TLogType,T>
  where TRevision : IRevision<T> 
  where TLogType : IRevisionLog
{ ... }
```

This code compiles fine, but I am wondering, is this last one T really needed?
When i implement IRevision I will be passing type T, so there is really no need to duplicate type.

My demo implementation would be:

```
public class HgRevision : IRevision<string>
{ ...}

public class HgLog : IRevisionLog
{ ... }

public class Hg : IRevisionControl<HgRevision, HgLog, string>
```

I'm passing string twice. I'm wondering if i could do anything like this:

```
public interface IRevisionControl<in TRevision, TLogType>
  where TRevision : IRevision
  where TLogType : IRevisionLog
{ ... }
```

So my Hg would be:

```
public class Hg : IRevisionControl<HgRevision, HgLog>
```

Of course, this last snippet does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This code compiles fine, but I am wondering, is this last one T really needed?

Yes, assuming you actually need the constraint on `TRevision`. If you don't, that's fine... but if you do, you need to be able to specify *which* `IRevision<T>` there has to be a conversion to.

One option would be to create a base interface for `IRevision<>`:

```
public interface IRevision
{
    // Include any members which don't depend on TRevisionType
}

public interface IRevision<TRevisionType> : IRevision
{
    // The rest
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
public interface IRevisionControl<in TRevision, TLogType>
  where TRevision : IRevision 
  where TLogType : IRevisionLog
```

... but of course you then won't be able to use any of the members declared in `IRevision<>` - only the ones in the non-generic base interface.

Comment: I am fully aware of limitations of this solution, but I will use concrete type HgRevision in my Hg class, so this is OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, that you need `TRevision` in declaration of `IRevisionControl`? I mean, it would make sense in class declaration, because some code in the class methods can work only with specific `TRevision`, but in interface, maybe, this will be enough:

```
public interface IRevisionControl<TRevisionType, TLogType>
  where TLogType : IRevisionLog
{
     void Foo(IRevision<TRevisionType> revision);
}
```

?

Comment: Using this pattern i can not force TRevisionType to be implemented from IRevision

Comment: According to your code, `TRevisionType` shouldn't be implemented from `IRevision`, its a type argument for `IRevision`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, typo. I want to have TRevision implemented by IRevision<TRevisionType>. I want to use concrete types in my IRevisionControl implementation. Skeet's way is OK.