# Would Scala eliminate the need for repetition here?

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

Was just looking at this question: [removing redundant type in Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912445/removing-redundant-type-in-interface/).  Turns out not to be possible to eliminate type parameter `T` in C#.  Is this related to higher-kinded types?  Does Scala fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with higher-kinded types. The question is, does `IRevisionControl` need to know `T`? If not, you can use an existential type

```
trait Revision[RevisionType]
trait RevisionLog

trait RevisionControl[R <: Revision[_], L <: RevisionLog]
```

If you need `T`, you either have to add it as another type parameter...

```
trait RevisionControl[T, R <: Revision[T], L <: RevisionLog]
```

...or you use a type member in `Revision`...

```
trait Revision {
  type RevisionType
}

trait RevisionControl[R <: Revision, L <: RevisionLog] {
  def foo: R#RevisionType = ???
}
```